# Social Studio Data Model

Tags: radian6

I am looking for social studio data model, how social studio save the posts. Is there any one who is aware of social studio data model?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Social Studio integration uses the Social Post object in Salesforce, to view this go to Setup>Build>Social Media>Social Post in Classic.

In lightning click setup and go to Object Manager and search for Social Post.

Likewise it uses the same Social Persona object as other social media integration which you can view by using the same searches except changing 'Social Post' to 'Social Persona'.